# ANDROID Force user to use certain buttons on keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am creating an Android app where the user can convert between decimal, hex, and binary. For example, if the user is inputting a binary number, I don't want them to insert letters when the Android keyboard pops up.

for binary the user can only put in 1's and 0's.
for hex the user can only put numbers 0-9 and letters a-f
for decimal numbers 0-9

Comment: Have you considered using a `TextChangedListener`. In the listener, you can detect what was typed and remove it if it was invalid. If you are interested, I can post a solution.

Comment: You can use android:digits="0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm" which will only allow digits and a-z that too in small letter only.

Comment: @AmulyaKhare that would be great thank you!!

Comment: make all logics from Electronic there will be if else conditions if((i=0)||(i=1)||(i=2)....(i=9)||(i=a)....||(i=f) where int a=10.or 67 to 92 ..etc; then you can get values of alphabets then conversion logic you have to make

Answer (score 0):

Android `EditText` has set of defined `inputTypes` and each type bring appropriate keyboard up for user.

`<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:inputType="date"
//or        android:inputType="number"
//or        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
//or        android:inputType="datetime"
//or        android:inputType="textWebEmailAddress"
// and alot more...
        />`

If android `inputTypes` does not match your needs, your probably should create your own keyboard.